# What are the major security differences between Chromium and Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox

I'm not sure how to get an informed, unbiased comparison between the security models of Firefox and Chromium. I've tried to google it, but all I find are uninformed anecdotes from random news sites, and most of the results are outdated and not talking about current versions of these browsers.

The general consensus seems to be that Chromium is superior in terms of security because of its better sandboxing implementation, but I don't know if that's even true. What are the major differences between the security models of the two browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome handles web content of tabs (including javascript execution) within sandboxed processes. This means that even if Chrome's javascript engine has an exploitable bug such as a buffer overflow or memory corruption vulnerability which can be used by an attacker to get remote code execution, then the attacker's code still can't get access to the user's filesystem without another exploit against a second bug in the sandbox system itself.

Firefox doesn't use a process sandbox like this, so a single vulnerability in its javascript engine for example is all that's needed for an attacker to get access to your filesystem, etc. Firefox uses a single process for most of everything currently, which means that it can't make effective use of process sandboxing. There is ongoing work on this as part of the [e10s](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) project.